# What are some database like websites about lower levels of economics (micro/macro) for a research project?

Tags: self-study, research

I'm looking for some websites; books or videos on the beginning levels of economics like micro and macro economics to do a research project projects on.  I found some course videos but they were a bit confusing.  I'm not sure what specific fields I'm supposed to begin with but I'm looking for but the lower levels of subject in both micro and macro economics.

What are some clear and trustworthy resources you recommend.  One's like database with the reference links (works cited) would be really good.

Answer (score 2):

[Fama-French library](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html)
has good data on which you can test your first Fama-French regression model.

I have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc1L3zjsgiY) on Youtube that might help you with this first project.

Ps.: It would help a lot if you were more specific about what you want to learn. I can give other suggestions, but I really don't know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in inequality? I highly recommend [this database](http://wid.world) made by Thomas Piketty. Here's [his TED lecture](https://www.ted.com/talks/thomas_piketty_new_thoughts_on_capital_in_the_twenty_first_century) on the topic, too.